In Postscript, does loading a dictionary to run a procedure have the same overhead as doing a lookup of the procedure name in the dict?
/myDict<<
           /myProc {
               (Hello world) =
           }
>>def

myDict begin %A
myProc       %A
end          %A

myDict /myProc get exec %B

Given the above Postscript code, which (not surprisingly) produces the following output using ghostscript (GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27) on Linux):
Hello world
Hello world 

The %A lines pushes the whole dictionary and any state it might have onto the dict stack; I don't think this is true for the line marked %B, as I believe it just does a lookup and runs the procedure it finds, without loading the dictionary onto the dict stack .
I am interested for times where the dict is very large and loading it (perhaps many times) would have significant overhead.
Context: Running in ghostscript.
Question: Does the last line (myDict /myProc get exec  %B) have less overhead than the lines which are marked with %A?

The answer is that it depends on the implementation. However in general in PostScript there is no practical difference between them. You need to load the dictionary in both cases in order to find the packed executable array. Whether you also store a pointer to it on the dictionary stack or not makes very little difference. Pushing a pointer to the dictionary onto the stack means that subsequent calls to its content will be slightly faster due to not having to search all the dictionaries on the stack.
